# pyqt5 video widget and table widget side by side

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to have a table widget side by side to a video widget and a webview widget. The video and webview widget to be stacked vertically. 
I tried to first have table widget and video widget side by side but the video widget is being hidden by the table widget. I'm able to hear audio so the video seems to be running but just doesn't seem to be displaying the video part. 
What is wrong in the code? 
Pasting the sample code. I'm yet to add the web widget.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget,QVBoxLayout,
    QTableWidgetItem, QLabel, QHBoxLayout,QGridLayout)

class Window(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()
        table1 = QTableWidget()
        table1.setRowCount(2)
        table1.setColumnCount(2)
        table1.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
        table1.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
        table1.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
        table1.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))

        self.VideoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("test.mp4")))
        self.player.play()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.VideoWidget)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(table1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.VideoWidget)

        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        self.move(0,0)
        self.resize(320, 240)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Everything works fine for me if I use an absolute path (and set a sane window size).

Comment: I kept the video in the same folder as the script. I confirmed that the video is being played as I hear audio. Also if I disable the table widget then I see video being played. Also I tried setting the self.resize(320, 240) to 640x480 but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using QSplitter. 
The code is as below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget,QVBoxLayout,
    QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout,QSplitter,QGroupBox)
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()

        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.splitter = QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        self.left = QGroupBox('Left')

        self.table1 = QTableWidget()
        self.table1.setRowCount(2)
        self.table1.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table1.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
        self.table1.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
        self.table1.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
        self.table1.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))

        self.left_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.left)
        self.left_layout.addWidget(self.table1)

        self.right = QGroupBox('Right')
        self.VideoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("test.mp4")))
        self.player.play()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.VideoWidget)

        self.webview = QWebView()
        url = "https://www.google.com"
        self.webview.load(QUrl(url))

        self.right_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.right)
        self.right_layout.addWidget(self.webview)

        self.right_layout.addWidget(self.VideoWidget)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.left)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.right)

        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.resize(840,680)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I've edited my post and have posted working example. For the crash issue with Google maps I've started a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753808/pyqt5-table-video-webview-showing-gmaps-give-seg-fault-on-ubuntu