# pyqt5 table+ video+ webview showing gmaps give seg fault on ubuntu

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've a sample code which has a Table widget, A video widget and webview widget that shows google maps. his code works without any issue on Windows machine but when I try to run the same code on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine + PyQt5 5.10.1 I start getting segmentation fault when I run the script multiple times.

The crash happens only when I load Google maps. If I simply load google.com then I don't see any crash. Am I missing something?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget,QVBoxLayout,
    QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout,QSplitter,QGroupBox)
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()

        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.splitter = QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        self.left = QGroupBox('Left')

        self.table1 = QTableWidget()
        self.table1.setRowCount(2)
        self.table1.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table1.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))
        self.table1.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,2)"))
        self.table1.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,1)"))
        self.table1.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (2,2)"))

        self.left_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.left)
        self.left_layout.addWidget(self.table1)

        self.right = QGroupBox('Right')
        self.VideoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("test.mp4")))
        self.player.play()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.VideoWidget)

        self.webview = QWebView()
        url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + str(50.0621004) + "," + str(8.5608973)
        self.webview.load(QUrl(url))

        self.right_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.right)
        self.right_layout.addWidget(self.webview)

        self.right_layout.addWidget(self.VideoWidget)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.left)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.right)

        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.resize(840,680)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: As you have installed PyQt5 5.10.1, ubuntu does not have an updated version in its packages, I have executed it in Arch Linux and I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/JRyEIcu

Comment: At my side it works 1 or 2 times. But when I execute 3 or 4th time it starts giving me seg fault when the google maps load completes. If I make some changes in the script, it works for 1 or 2 times again and then starts crashing again.

Comment: I don't see crash if only webview widgets is enabled and video vidget and table widget is disabled.

Comment: I checked this further and I see this issue only when I add webview widget in a layout and try to load google maps.